# Determining what a regular expression does

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

I am given the regular expression

$(\lambda|a)(\lambda|bb)(\lambda|ccc)$

and I'm trying to describe what this set does in the form $\{x|\text{x begins and ends with a}\}$ or something similar. This set is giving me trouble. I am trying to split this up into sets, so like this:

$(\{\lambda,a\})(\{\lambda,bb\})(\{\lambda,ccc\})$

From there I concatenate to get:

$\{\lambda, a, bb, ccc, abb, accc, bbccc, abbccc\}$

But from here I can't really tell what this set is doing in terms of [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). Can anyone help me figure out what the description of this set would be?

Comment: If I'm using the right notation convention, $(\lambda | a)(\lambda | bb)(\lambda |ccc)$ means you pick one from the first pair, one from the second, and one from the third. Thus all your combinations are

$$\{\lambda \lambda \lambda, \lambda \lambda ccc, \lambda bb \lambda, \lambda bb ccc, a \lambda \lambda, a\lambda ccc, a bb \lambda, a bb ccc\}$$

Comment: @AlexisOlson Do we have to include $\lambda$ that many times though? Isn't what I have saying the same thing?

Comment: Yes, unless $\lambda$ is your notation for the empty string (more commonly denoted $\varepsilon$).

Comment: What would the set builder notation be for this set then?

Comment: I don't see any simple way of expressing it in set builder notation that isn't basically just rewriting the regular expression.

Comment: Indeed.  $\{x\Vert y\Vert z: x\in \{\lambda, \mathrm{a}\}, y\in\{\lambda, \mathrm{bb}\}, z\in\{\lambda, \mathrm{ccc}\}\}$  Where $\Vert$ is the (string)concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the description as a product of three languages looks like the simplest description. If you really insist to have a different description, you could do the following. Let
$$
L = \{u \in \{a,b,c\}^* \mid \text{the letters of $u$ occur in strict alphabetic order} \}
$$
Thus $L = \{\lambda, a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc\}$. Now your language is $f(L)$ where $f: \{a,b,c\}^* \to \{a,b,c\}^*$ is the homomorphism defined by $f(a) = a$, $f(b) = bb$ and $f(c) = ccc$.